# Why does a method with a pointer receiver still work when it receives a value?

Tags: pointers, methods, go

I was just playing with [Exercise 51 in the Tour of Go](http://tour.golang.org/#51). The explanation claims the `Scale` method has no effect when it receives a `Vertex` instead of a pointer to a `Vertex`.

Yet when I change the declaration `v := &Vertex{3, 4}` to `v := Vertex{3, 4}` in `main` the only change in the output is the missing `&` to mark the pointer.

So why does `Scale` change the variable it receives even if the variable isn't a pointer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It does not "receive" a value. Go is strongly typed, so if somewhere a pointer to T is prescribed, a pointer to T (`*T`) is the only option which can happen as a value for such typed place.

The "magic" is in the compiler which effectively "rewrites" your code under certain [conditions](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Calls):

> A method call `x.m()` is valid if the method set of (the type of) `x` contains `m` and the argument list can be assigned to the parameter list of `m`. If `x` is addressable and &x's method set contains `m`, `x.m()` is shorthand for `(&x).m()`:

Related: [Method sets](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_sets)

Comment: So, while `v` isn't a pointer in my case. `Scale` can simply treat it as if it were one?

Comment: No, `Scale` **cannot** treat a non pointer as a pointer. The specs excerpt in the answer explains why `Scale` will get `&v` as its receiver, **not** `v`.

Comment: Ok. But **I** can apply pointer methods to values just as if they were pointers themselves. Thanks for explaining this!

Comment: Take into account that those values must be addressable. You can not use a literal, for instance.

Answer (score 1):

The difference that the tour suggests isn't actually in changing `v := &Vertex{3, 4}` to `v:= Vertex{3, 4}`, but rather in changing the definitions of the two methods so that they work on values instead of pointers. So, for example, for `Scale`, `func (v *Vertex) Scale(f float64) {...` becomes `func (v Vertex) Scale(f float64) {...` (note that `(v *Vertex)`, a pointer value, becomes `(v Vertex)`, a non-pointer value). In both cases, you should leave the declaration of `v` as `v := &Vertex{3, 4}`.

You'll notice that in the first case, when the methods take pointers, the output is `&{15 20} 25`. However, when the methods take values rather than pointers, the output is `&{3 4} 5`.

In both cases, `v` is a pointer to a `Vertex` object. In the first case, the pointer is passed to the methods, and everything works as expected - any modifications made to the `Vertex` object are made to the original value, so those changes persist after the method returns. In the second case, though `v` is still a pointer, the Go compiler is smart enough to convert `v.Scale(5)` to `(*v).Scale(5)`, where `v` is dereferenced, and the resulting value is passed to `Scale`.