# Why method with "value receiver" work with "pointer caller"?

Tags: go

I'm new in **Go**. I'm reading about method receiver.

And have a little confuse why value receiver accept pointer type, and in the example below, the name wasn't changed even with pointer type.

I've got this result:

```
Employee name: Mark Andrew
Employee name: Mark Andrew
Employee name: Mark Andrew
```

```html
package main

import (
 "fmt"
)

type Employee struct {
 name string
 age  int
}

/*
Method with value receiver
*/
func (e Employee) changeName(newName string) {
 e.name = newName
}

/*
Method with pointer receiver
*/
func (e *Employee) changeAge(newAge int) {
 e.age = newAge
}

func main() {
 e := Employee{
  name: "Mark Andrew",
  age:  50,
 }
 
 // this work perfectly
 fmt.Printf("Employee name: %s", e.name)
 e.changeName("Michael Andrew")
 
 // ofcourse, the name isn't changed => good
 fmt.Printf("\nEmployee name: %s", e.name)
 
 // but why this work too?
 // and why the name wasn't changed? => confused ...
 (&e).changeName("Hallo")
 fmt.Printf("\nEmployee name: %s", e.name)
}
```

Comment: I know that the question have something same with: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17996771/why-does-a-method-with-a-pointer-receiver-still-work-when-it-receives-a-value
But they're different

Comment: the name has not changed because the receiver is not a pointer.

Comment: @zerkms As i understand, with value receiver, the "caller" will be cloned and all modification will not effect to "real caller".
So how do Go handle the case (&e).changeName("Hallo") ?

Comment: If the "caller" is cloned same with e.changeName("Michael Andrew"), so is (&e) meaningless?

Comment: It's handled the same way - the value a pointer points to is copied and then used as a receiver. See "Such a function indirects through the receiver to create a value to pass as the receiver to the underlying method; the method does not overwrite the value whose address is passed in the function call." at https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_expressions

Comment: Thanks, I've got it